# Text inside div tags does not come out right size

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with making text inside of div tags be the size that I request it to be (in pixels). Say I want the font-size to be 20px, but I want the div size to be 250 by 50 pixels. However, the text seems to take the size of the div and becomes stretched out. Here is the code I am using:

```
.NavBarHome {    
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue";
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    width:250px;
    height:50px;
    text-height:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#161616;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:50px;    
}
```

What can I do to make the text the size I want? I've used this script numerous times before and it worked just fine, but for some reason it just doesn't work this time. Any advice?

Comment: works fine chrome, ff, ie [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1k33e2z6/)

Comment: Can you make an example of this issue? I really want to know how the text gets stretched out :)

Comment: The text just takes the size of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `max-width:250px` to your CSS:

```css
.NavBarHome {    
  font-family:"Helvetica Neue";
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:center;
  width:250px;
  max-width:250px;
  height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#161616;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:50px;    
}
```

```html
<div> 
  <div></div> 
  <div class="NavBarHome">Home</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to help. I think it might have helped before, but right now it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Can you post an example where it is not working? I need more than just your one class to know what the problem is.

Comment: Here is the code:

`
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">

.NavBarHome {
 font-family:"Helvetica Neue";
 font-size:20px;
 text-align:center;
 width:200px;
 max-width:200px;
 height:50px;
 max-height:50px;
 text-height:20px;
 display:inline-block;
 background-color:#161616;
 color:#fff;
 line-height:50px;
}

 
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div>

<div></div>
<div class="NavBarHome">Home</div>

</div>
`

I want "Home" to be font-size 20 but instead it takes the size of the div

Comment: I created a runnable version of your code and it looks ok to me. Is your code working differently?

Comment: That is exactly what I want the code to be doing, but it seems to be making the Home div the size of the entire page, along with the other 2 divs.

Comment: There must be another style interfering. Check the following link to learn how to use Chrome dev tools to debug styling problems: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles

Comment: I think it might just be my version of Dreamweaver as I tried it out on another computer and it worked fine.